# How to remove .php and get var after slash on .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day. I need to remove .php at the end of a file and also get the last /var into a php $_GET var from .Htaccess.

I want this url rewrite:

```
    http://example.com/file/123
```

into

```
    http://example.com/file.php?id=123
```

But this must work if file is index.php like this:

```
    http://example.com/123
```

into

```
    http://example.com/index.php?id=123
```

Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Sr. just one more thing. If id is not present in http://example.com/file/ it shows the index.php file. is there somehow to fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify with example what you mean by `If id is not present in example.com/file`?

Comment: I mean. when I access to "example.com/file/" without the last slash id "123". It doesn't show the file.php it shows index.php

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your needs

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+) http://example.com/file.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

This is a great article on the subject http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this in .htaccess for remove the extensions :

> RewriteEngine On
>    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

And if you need a new extension add as many lines you want

> RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

For more info read : https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/